# filter values of an object by keys given from an array and render them in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this

```
const myObject ={
2: {id: 2, name: "Lori Kreiger Jr.", email: "swift.tiana@example.net", avatar: null, gender: "m"}
3: {id: 3, name: "Kurt Yost", email: "amacejkovic@example.org", avatar: null, gender: "f"}
4: {id: 4, name: "Norene Hilpert", email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m"}
5: {id: 5, name: "Crawford Pouros:,  email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m"}
}
```

and an array containing the ids that i will have to filter from this object

```
const myArray = [2,5];
```

In the React code i want to loop through *myObject* filtering it by ids that i have on *myArray* and passing its values to my component

```
<ListView id={id} name={name} email={email} ...etc />
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: In this case, you may use an Array to store these items instead of Object because all of them has same structure and your keys are non-sense.

Comment: @Pylon It's a redux principle so i try to follow them. https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you filter `myObject`:

```js
Object.values(myObject).filter(({ id }) => myArray.includes(id));
```

Here's a live example:

```js
'use strict';

const myObject = {
  '2': { id: 2, name: "Lori Kreiger Jr.", email: "swift.tiana@example.net", avatar: null, gender: "m" },
  '3': { id: 3, name: "Kurt Yost", email: "amacejkovic@example.org", avatar: null, gender: "f" },
  '4': { id: 4, name: "Norene Hilpert", email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m" },
  '5': { id: 5, name: "Crawford Pouros:",  email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m"}
}

const myArray = [2, 5];

const result = Object.values(myObject).filter(({ id }) => myArray.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for better performance, as it can perform lookups in `O(1)` time.

```js
const myObject ={
2: {id: 2, name: "Lori Kreiger Jr.", email: "swift.tiana@example.net", avatar: null, gender: "m"},
3: {id: 3, name: "Kurt Yost", email: "amacejkovic@example.org", avatar: null, gender: "f"},
4: {id: 4, name: "Norene Hilpert", email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m"},
5: {id: 5, name: "Crawford Pouros:",  email: "julie62@example.com", avatar: null, gender: "m"}
}
const myArray = [2,5];
const set = new Set(myArray);
const res = Object.values(myObject).filter(obj=>set.has(obj.id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter the Object values to get an Array of the desired values
2. Map the filtered values to be a list of React elements and pass the relevant props

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const MY_OBJECT = {
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lori Kreiger Jr.",
    email: "swift.tiana@example.net",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kurt Yost",
    email: "amacejkovic@example.org",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "f"
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: "Norene Hilpert",
    email: "julie62@example.com",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: "Crawford Pouros",
    email: "julie62@example.com",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  }
};
const MY_ARRAY = [2, 5];

const ListView = ({ id, name }) => <li>{name}</li>;

const App = () => {
  const filteredList = Object.values(MY_OBJECT).filter(e => MY_ARRAY.includes(e.id));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My List</h1>
      <ul>
        { filteredList.map(l => <ListView name={l.name} key={l.id} />) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
 };

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach will be iterating to your filter list. Consider below functional component:

```js
const MY_OBJECT = {
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lori Kreiger Jr.",
    email: "swift.tiana@example.net",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kurt Yost",
    email: "amacejkovic@example.org",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "f"
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: "Norene Hilpert",
    email: "julie62@example.com",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: "Crawford Pouros",
    email: "julie62@example.com",
    avatar: null,
    gender: "m"
  }
};
const MY_ARRAY = [2, 5];
const ListView = ({ id, name }) => <li>{name}</li>;
const App = () => {
  
return (
    MY_ARRAY.map(val => {
        const { id, name } = MY_OBJECT[val];
        return (
            < ListView id={id} name={name} />
        )
    })

)
 };

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```